# What does %3.1f do in C?

Tags: c

I am reading through an old school (1990) book on C and they have a number formatting in it which loops like this:

```
... 
...
printf("%3.1f %15.10f\n",x, x*x+x+1/x);
```

In the book it says that it

> `%m.kf` Converts a value of type **float** (or **double**) to `m` decimal positions with `k` digits after the period.

After playing around with this I am still completely baffled.

I played around with this. 
http://cstub.com/196059842/

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    double f = 1.55568;
    printf("%10.12f",f);
}
```

`1.555680824083`

Comment: 1.555680824083 has 12 digits after the decimal point -- What part is baffeling you?

Comment: @Soren What does the `10` part do then (`%10.12`)?

Comment: @Johnston minimal field width, as with practically any similar conversion specifier.

Comment: It is the total width of the field, but 10 is smaller than 12 so it is ignored

Comment: I remember I had the same reaction when I saw that code for the first time, +1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prints a floating point number with 1 precision and 3 characters minimum width, so for example

```
printf("%3.1f\n", 3.5);
```

would output

```
3.5
```

because it has 3 characters `3` `.` and `5`, but

```
printf("%10.1f\n", 3.5);
```

would output

```
       3.5
_______---
/* ^ 7 spaces because 10 characters width requested */
```

This would allow you to right align numbers like

```
printf("%10.1f\n", 3.5);
printf("%10.1f\n", 121.2);
printf("%10.1f\n", 54.7);
```

output

```
       3.5
     121.2
      54.7
```

Comment: What is the actual use of `10` in `10.1f`? Why wouldn't you just write 1 every time? What do people use that for?

Comment: @Johnston Suppose you want your output aligned.

Answer (score 5):

Check this example:

```
double f = 1.234;
printf("%10.2f",f); // 10 positions wide, 2 decimals at most
```

Output:

```
      1.23 <- print only 2 decimal digits
^^^^^^^^^^
||||||||||
0123456789 <- positions
```

Such code is a bit *common* when you want to output statistics and you want everything to be nicely aligned.

---

In your example:

```
double f = 1.55568;
printf("%10.12f",f);
```

You say to print at maximum 12 digits after the period. Of course, the number has more digits than you wrote when assigning the value, because of its representation.

You also say that what gets printed should have 10 positions at the minimum, which means that if the number is not big enough, whitespaces will be placed before the number so that the requirement is met.